# Using docker image on local file

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am new to docker, and I created an image.  It is a pipeline for data analysis, and takes a single input file which it runs multiple applications on and returns some documents of results.  My question is if there is a way to run this image on a file without having to upload to file to the image.  Something along these lines:

sudo docker run username/pipeline python /home/username/pipeline.py localfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-v` (`--volume`) parameter to `docker run` to expose parts of your local filesystem inside a container.  For details see [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems).

For example, you could do something like:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/data ...
```

And inside the container, you current directory would be available as `/data`.  Your applications could operate on files in that directory and create new files there, and they would be visible to you immediately on the host.

Note that because by default everything in your Docker container will be running as `root` you can end up with permissions issues.  There are various ways of solving that problem, the simplest of which is to run `chown` on the files after the container is finished.